# Importing bulk database in phpmyadmin using xampp

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp

I recently installed xampp to run backup of my wordpress site.
I am trying to import my database backup in phpmyadmin.
Database size is more than 2 mb, so I changed all necessary things like:

```
file_uploads
upload_max_filesize
post_max_size
memory_limit
max_input_time
max_execution_time
```

in php.ini-production and php.ini-development but import still not happening.
Error is like: No data was received to import. Either no file name was submitted, or the file size exceeded the maximum size permitted by your PHP configuration.

Answer (score 1):

I think that php.ini-production and php.ini-development are just examples and you need to find the real php.ini to make your changes there. To verify what I'm saying, have a look at a phpinfo page to see whether the parameters have been changed. Also, you need to restart Apache after the changes.